# Querying duplicate values and selecting column values acording to them

Tags: select, hive, duplicates

[image]

I need to extract the numbers from the table TEST which has more than two area types and has the area ="three" as a value. I should get the results "b" and "f".

Thank you.

Comment: It is not clear what result do you want? Just `a` and `f` or all rows with number a and f. Also add data example for your second condition -  `has more than two area types`. And please use text, not pictures, it is wasting of time if someone needs to input the data from your picture for testing query

Comment: sorry. i need to extract unique numbers from "number " column where there is more than once ,, count(number)>1 and also it should have "three"  in one of the multiple entries . so from above table result is b,f . even though "d" has multiple entries is does not contain "three"

Answer (score 0):

Below are the queries -

```
select count(*), number from <tableName> where number in (select number from <tableName> where area='three') group by number having count(*)>1;

select number from <tableName> group by number having count(*)>1 and sum(case when area='Three' then 1 else 0) = 1;
```